# Checking whether two pointers are in the same block of memory

Tags: c, pointers

This is a homework question that I am confused on how to approach.  There are restrictions as well were I cannot use /, %, or any loops.  Given a method, it accepts two pointers of type int.  Taking these two pointer I need to find whether they are in the same block of memory or in different block of memory.  If case one I return 1 for them being in the same block if and 0 otherwise.  So my thinking is that if two pointers are in the same block of memory that must mean they point to the same integer?  Im not sure if this is correct any hint in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: That depends on what "the same block of memory" means for your assignment.

Comment: Same block usually means "they are pointing to the same memory give or take a few kB". That means that the top bits of the address are the same - the bottom bits will be different. If you know how big a block is, you know how many bits should be the same. Enough of a hint?

Comment: Do you understand how bit masking works? `0x123456 & 0xFFFF00 = 0x123400`; but `0x123465 & 0xFFFF00 = 0x123400` as well...

Comment: By "two pointers of type int", do you mean "two pointers of type `int*`"?

Comment: Can you confirm what "same block of memory" means? @Floris's speculation is likely correct, but the idea of a "block of memory" does not exist in standard C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floris basically gave you the idea; here's my actual implementation for POSIX:

```
uintptr_t pagesz = getpagesize();
uintptr_t addr_one = (uintptr_t)ptr1;
uintptr_t addr_two = (uintptr_t)ptr2;

bool in_same_page = (addr_one & ~(pagesz - 1)) == (addr_two & ~(pagesz - 1));
```

Comment: That makes sense for POSIX -- *assuming* that the conversion from a pointer to `uintptr_t` is well-behaved in some sense. It's invalid for C in general; there's no undefined behavior, but the result is not guaranteed (by the C standard) to be at all meaningful.

Comment: Aren't you off by at least one? You need `~(pagesz-1)` if you want all the top bits set. Anyway I thought for homework I would leave OP a little bit of work which is why I wrote the comment hints rather than the full solution. Fizz on!

Comment: @Floris Correct, I forgot the subtraction.

Comment: @KeithThompson But who would want to write that in portable C? The C standard doesn't even know about memory paging. OP wanted a solution, I provided one that should work (and I mentioned the conditions required for it to work). Basically, you're right but I didn't write anything different either.

Comment: I was adding information, not necessarily criticizing your answer. The OP might not know that the task is inherently non-portable, and might not be using POSIX.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming that you know how large the blocks of memory are (I assume 1k (2^10)) you can subtract the smaller address from the larger and see if the difference is less than the block size -1.

```
int same_block(int x, int y){

   int difference;

   if(x > y){
      difference = x - y;
   } else {
      difference = y - x;
   }

   if(difference < 1024){
      return 1;
   }

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: This is wrong, if the one address is 1000, the other is 1500, this will yield true, although they don't reside in the same block.